How do you invert a grep -P command?
I have a bunch of output files that also printed the entire text of the script that made them. Let's say each of these files, which are the output of "oops.sh", looks like this:
Hello world!
This script is called #!bash
scriptName=$(echo $0)
echo """Hello world!
This script is called $scriptName."""
# Wait, WTF just happened?
echo "Done.".
Done.

I'd like to use a grep or sed command to remove the text of the original script. The output should look like this:
Hello world!
This script is called .
Done.

I've successfully matched what I want to remove -- grep -Pazo "(?s)\#\!bash.*?Done\.\"" outputOops.txt -- but I can't seem to invert the results. (I don't actually know Perl, BTW, and regrettably I don't currently have time to learn it. I got this far based on some StackOverflow answers, but didn't understand other relevant answers well enough to use them.) Each of the following returns nothing --
grep -Pazov "(?s)\#\!bash.*?Done\.\"" outputOops.txt
grep -Pazo -v "(?s)\#\!bash.*?Done\.\"" outputOops.txt
grep -Pazo --invert-match "(?s)\#\!bash.*?Done\.\"" outputOops.txt
grep -Pazo "(?s)(?!)\!bash.*?Exiting\.\"" outputOops.txt
 grep -Pazo "(?s)(?!)(\!bash.*?Exiting\.\")" outputOops.txt

-- except the last two lines, which both return -bash: !: event not found.
What am I doing wrong? Does negation just not work with the -P flag? If not, what can I do instead?

Just use single quotes around your regex. In double quotes the shell tries to use history expansion because of the ! ... P.S.: This isn't really a programming question and should be over at [unix.se].

grep is a bad choice for this - it'd be easy with sed, awk, perl, python, ruby, etc., I'm not even sure if it's possible in general with grep.


Not possible with grep and 2. Definitely a suitable question for stackoverflow since it requires regex help


grep -Fvxf script-file output-file?

@Shawn Close, but there are a number of lines that actually should appear both in the script and its output, and this deletes them both times (because it matches line-by-line rather than the whole file).

@EdMorton , how would you do it with sed?

@tink, unfortunately, grep -Pazo '(?s)(?!)(\!bash.*?Exiting\.\")' outputOops.txt also returns nothing.

Imagine the original regexp for what you want to print is a.b - in grep you'd write grep -o 'a.b' while in sed you could write sed 's/.*\(a.b\).*/\1/g'. To get the rest of the text in sed would just be sed 's/\(.*\)a.b\(.*\)/\1\2/g' while grep simply isn't designed to edit text. I'm simplifying a bit but you get the idea. A problem you have, though, is you wrote PCREs to do the original match and neither sed nor awk support those so if you want to keep those regexps it may be time to learn perl or python or maybe ruby.

Re "unfortunately, grep -Pazo '(?s)(?!)(\!bash.*?Exiting\.\")' outputOops.txt also returns nothing", (?!) matches nothing. That pattern will never match.

@ikegami, I did, back in the question: I want everything except what the original grep command matches. Apparently I'm using Perl negation wrong, though, if (?!) matches nothing -- no surprise, haha.

@EdMorton, thank you! Will that work across multiple lines? I've been having a beast of a time getting sed to recognize newline characters as anything other than a stop-searching-here mark.

@Photosynthetic If you need to cross lines there are various ways to do it, including GNU sed's -z option which reads the whole file into memory at once. Honestly, though, I'd use GNU awk for this which CAN do the same but probably wouldn't have to as you could define RS to be the regexp you want to match and then every $0 is the parts around it.

There are three things you print with grep The lines that match, the lines that don't match, and the part of the line that matched. Using -z, you effectively defined the whole file as a line, and you want to print the start and end of the "line", but not the middle. That's not one of the three things grep can output. So using -z won't work. Not using -z won't work either, because whether the middle lines are included or not depends on something outside of the line. This can't be done using grep.

@Ed Morton, I figured out what you mean and have already deleted my comment.

For example, "(?s)\#\!bash.*?Done\.\"" is a PCRE so I've no idea what it means (only been Unix programming for 42 years, I'm sure a use for PCREs is right around the corner :-) ) but let's pretend it means something like #!bash.*Done in an ERE. With GNU awk you could do gawk -v RS='#!bash.*Done' '{print RT}' to print the matching strings and if you wanted to print the strings that don't match instead it'd just be gawk -v RS='#!bash.*Done' '{print $0}'. I expect you can do similar in perl, python, or ruby if you want to stick with PCREs rather than figure out equivalent EREs.

@ikegami So there's no way to print the part of the line that didn't match? Makes sense. Drat. Thank you though!

perl -0777ne'print /#!bash.*?Done\."/s ? "$\$'''" : $_' $`is the portion of the string before the match.$'` is the portion that follows.

@ikegami That did it! Thank you so much! (Now to teach myself enough Perl that I can do that next time...)

@Ed Morton. Re "is a PCRE so I've no idea what it means", #!bash, followed by any number of characters including new line, followed by Done.". But .*? will match the fewest characters possible at the position where it starts matching (so it will match up to the first Done." and not the second).

@ikegami ah, I see, thanks. And does the leading (?s) mean the same as ([[:space:]]?) or ([[:space:]]*) or something else?

@Ed Morton, It enables the s flag, often seen as /.../s. The s flag makes . match any character. By default, . matches any characters except Line Feed. \s is what matches a whitespace character.

Simpler to just remove the middle: perl -0777pe's/#!bash.*?Done\."//s'

@ikegami I see, OK thanks again for the further explanation. I see at https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#fullstopdot that . without s doesn't match whatever the newline string is defined to be, typically either LF or CRLF. Gotta say, I wish the PCRE folks had just left . as meaning "any character" as it had since the dawn of regexps and introduced some escape sequence to mean "any character except newline" instead of changing the meaning of . to be that by default and then adding a flag s to give . back it's original/common meaning!

@Ed Morton, No, . always matches a CR. But keep in mind that CRLF might be converted to LF on read in Windows /// You say you want since-dawn behaviour, but that's exactly why . doesn't match LF. It emulates grep/sed/awk's line-by-line behaviour. PCRE got it from Perl which grew out of these tools. "s" stands for single-line, and is effectively allows match across lines, as if the whole string was a single line. Also note that Perl is from the 80s, so it's pretty close to dawn as well :)

I'm sure you already know but for the benefit of anyone else reading this - grep/sed/awk only read a line at a time by default but they can also read multiple lines at a time and . has never treated LF differently from any other character in any of those tools. There was a time before the 80s .... :-). Redefining . to exclude LF when existing regexps included it, and then adding s to un-redefine it so it once again means the same as in the previous regexps just seems like a zarre decision vs simply adding \X (where X is some character) to mean "any character except LF".

@Ed Morton, Re "but they can also read multiple lines at a time", And . can match any character. Both can override the default, but both work similarly (through different mechanisms) by default.  Using \X means they would work differently by default.

Regexps are simpler to read and write if . ALWAYS matches any character. Whether the buffer being matched  contains a newline or not is a different situation. If . always matches any character and sed, awk, perl, etc. read 1 line at a time by default then . means the same to all 3 tools. If someone decides to read multiple lines at a time with either tool then . still means the same thing to all 3 tools. If perl then decides to introduce \X it's no different than adding \w or \d and it's simpler than making . mean that and needing a separate s flag to make . match anything.

I suspect we'll have to agree to disagree, I just find the decision to require s to make . match any character instead of leaving . matching any character as in BREs/EREs and adding some escape sequence \X to mean "any but newline" bafflingly complicated and inconsistent (both within PCREs and between regexp variants) when PCREs already introduce escape sequences to match other sets of characters.

grep works on a line-by-line basis. Its output is based on whether the line matches pattern (or based on which part of the line was matched when -o is used).
Unfortunately, you need to output based on whether a different line matched. grep matches each line independently, so it can't do that.

But what if we change the definition of a line using -z. In a file without NUL characters, the whole file becomes a line.
There are three things you can print with grep:

The lines that match
The lines that don't match (-v)
The part of each line that matched (-o)

Unfortunately, none of those suit your needs since you want to print two disjoint parts of the "line".  grep only attempts to match each line once, so only one part of a line can match.

A simple Perl one-liner will do, however.
perl -0777pe's/#!bash.*?Done\."//s'

Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner
